# Remove layer or feature

Tags: openlayers, layers, vector

I want to remove existing vector layers on the map and

`map.getLayers().getSource();`

returns me `ol.source.Source` object as it stated in the [API](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html#getSource).

I cannot find the way how to jump from `ol.source.Source`to `ol.source.Vector` object. Everything I find in answers was to use something like this

`map.getLayers().getSource().getFeatures()`

which assumes that `getSource()` returns `ol.layer.Vector` I believe (generates error).

How to get to `ol.layer.Vector` from `map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`map.getLayers()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#getLayers) gives you a collection of all layers in the map, so you first have to select the vector layers out of this collection. This would be one way:

```
let vectorLayerArray = new Array();
map.getLayers().getArray().some(function(layer, i, array) {
  if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector) {
    vectorLayerArray.push(layer);
  }
}, this);
```

You would now have the array `vectorLayerArray` with all available vector layers. You can now iterate of that array an get the vector source from theses layers.

```
vectorLayerArray.forEach(function(aVecLayer) {
  aVecLayer.getSource();
})
```